# VBA macros excel

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo una hoja con botones ActiveX; Cada botón tiene una contraseña para abrir una hoja en específico. Cuando hago clic en cualquier botón me lleva a:

```
Private Sub Alpujarra_Click()
  formContra.Show     
End Sub

Private Sub btnAceptar_Click()
  Clave = txtClave
  Call Sedes
End Sub

Sub Sedes() 
  If Clave = "Alpu123" Then
     Sheets("Alpujarra").Visible = True
     Sheets("Alpujarra").Select
     Unload Me
  End if
```

Mi pregunta es:¿Cómo validar Clave y el botón a la vez (que sea el botón correspondiente a esa contraseña)? 
Espero me entiendan, y me puedan ayudar.